# Emails not inserting properly from txt file

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to insert some **e mails from a text file** into MySQL database, some of them are getting inserted properly but some of them are not.

My approach to implement this is like.

```
$query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'email-list.txt' INTO TABLE $tablename FIELDS TERMINATED BY 'r'(email)";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

some emails that are not inserted properly are like.

```
    xxxx7@yahoo.com
    xxx_xxxxx05@yahoo.com
```

These get inserted like.

```
    x
    xxx_xxxxx
```

Please see what is wrong in my approach and suggest any possible approach to do this properly.

Comment: Could you inlclude examples (in the exact format in the text file) of both records that are and are not being inserted into your database?

Comment: `FIELDS TERMINATED BY 'r'` should probably be `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r'` (edit s/FIELDS/LINES/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This...

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY 'r'
```

Did you mean...

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\r'
```

???

**THE DOCS**

> If you specify no FIELDS or LINES clause, the defaults are the same
>   as if you had written this:

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' STARTING BY ''
```

> (Backslash is the MySQL escape character within strings in SQL
>   statements, so to specify a literal backslash, you must specify two
>   backslashes for the value to be interpreted as a single backslash. The
>   escape sequences '\t' and '\n' specify tab and newline characters,
>   respectively.)

Comment: yes that was it, i forget to add `\r`, now its properly working

Comment: also can you tell me any way to find any duplicate entry while inserting the emails, i.e if an email is already inserted in database before, so it should not get inserted again in database. thanks

Comment: Well this isn't the place for convo, [SQL UNIQUE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Replace 
`FIELDS TERMINATED BY 'r'` with
`FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\r'`

Now, `r` is acting as termination character, so anything after `r` is getting removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
TERMINATED BY 'r'(email)";
```

Your terminating the email by the character 'r'

So when you are using

```
cricket4877@yahoo.com
```

it is truncating everything after the r, so it is only displaying the c.

You should change it to

```
TERMINATED BY '/r'(email);
```

P.S 
I hope that they are made up emails and not actual emails.